# can anyone identify why my css animation wosen't working

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm working with the React web applications. when I try to apply animation to code tag it wasen't showing the animation. My App.js is also simple and provided below

```
import './App.css';


export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <code>this is sample web page</code>
    </div>
  );
}
```

here is App.css

```
html{
  background-color: #282c34;
  color: white;
}
body{
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
  'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
  sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New',
    monospace;
    animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
}

.App {
  text-align: center;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

I try to change to another tag like h1 instead of code it's working with it normally.
note: using google chrome

Comment: Hi @Sri12866, the issue is from the default CSS styles of the <code> block conflicting with your custom styles. To resolve this, consider changing the <code> block to a <div> block.

Comment: Can you explain more in detail @DineshMsd why this happens

Comment: Hi @Sri12866 the <code> element is inline meaning that the `display: inline` is by deafult in <code>. if you add a class to the <code> element and apply `display: block` it will work, whats happening in behind is you're overriding the display property of the code to inline to block. the <div> element's default css is `display: block` that's why it's working for us initially!

Answer (score 1):

Add a wrapper to your `<code>` tag and set the animation on the wrapper.

For example:

```css
.code-wrapper{
  animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
}

.App {
  text-align: center;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="App">

  <div class="code-wrapper">
    <code>
      Hello world
    </code>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to apply the css to parent element **div** instead of **code**.
The reason is because **code** element is inline element and it could not be animated.

This is stated in the related [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/):

**Transformable element**

> A transformable element is an element in one of these categories:
>
> an element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is
> either a block-level or atomic inline-level element, or whose display
> property computes to table-row, table-row-group, table-header-group,
> table-footer-group, table-cell, or table-caption [CSS21]
>
> an element in the SVG namespace and not governed by the CSS box model
> which has the attributes transform, ‘patternTransform‘ or
> gradientTransform [SVG11].